# iOS Build uploaded but not visible in iTunes

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, assets, itunes

iOS build successfully uploading on iTunes and without any warning and error. Successfully verifies assets with iTunes.

But when I see iTunes activity section I cannot see any iOS build there. I receive email against every build I upload which state that some app icons are not found in build but these are icons are there in asset catalog and also successfully verified during upload.

Any clue what's going wrong there?

Comment: Have you verified the permission strings are included in the info.plist files or not? you might be using some services whose permission strings are not included in the info.plist file. iTunes doesn't show any warning/error but builds get rejected after successfull upload.

Comment: Yes, I verified. Actually, it was due to cocoa pods and I don't know why. Updating cocoa pods from pods app did the job...

Comment: I want to mark this Question Solved, I don't know how to do that. Suggestion please

Comment: As you have solved the issues on your own, I suggest you post a solution as an answer that worked for you and then accepts that answer to close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating pods did the work done... Don't know why but I just updated my pods from the cocoa pods app and it did the job for me... 
Note: In my case, I update pods twice (simply run an update, build an app, run update)